# Rsync previous half-copied files?

Tags: rsync

I found `rsync` behaves differently in the following two situations:

(1) All the files are copied by using `rsync`, then using `rsync` again will be fast (skip all the files);

(2) Use `cp` to copy files, then using rsync will be slow (or may be run freshly?)

So my confusion is "Does `rsync` generate any internal things on the files so that it can refer to avoid duplicate checking?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync -a` (in archive mode, which I presume you ran) retains all attributes of a file, including creation/modification time. `cp` does not. I suppose something in the file attributes that's different when you use `cp`, probably a later modification time, in the destination files, made `rsync` think they are newer files, so it either recopied them or had to check the contents.

Comment: Yes, I have used "-a" option. But when I remove "-a", `rsync` just skip the whole directory.

Comment: so there you have it :) rsync doesn't save any state, it just compares the current state of the 2 trees. You can set it to ignore modification times completely and only compare size, or you can set it to ignore modification times within a certain window. see `--size-only` in the man page.

Comment: Thanks Not_a_Golfer! But I have deleted some files in the destination (using `cp`), and rerun `rsync`, it just skip the directory. How is this? The option is `-v --size-only`.